# Reduction from Diophantine Equation Problem to Halting Problem

Tags: reductions, halting-problem, diophantine-equation

I want to study the reduction from the [Diophantine Equation Problem (Hilbert's tenth problem)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) to the [Halting problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Can you either explain it to me or give me a credible source from which I can study it?

Comment: The program is `if (the equation has a solution) then return 0 else <infinite loop>`.

Comment: @Dmitry, can I encourage you to write that in the answer box rather than a comment, so we can upvote it and the question can be treated as answered?  The Stack Exchange format discourages answering in comments.  I don't think you have to write anything more than that -- even a short answer is better than none.

Comment: worth noting this idea works to reduce *lots* of problems to the halting problem. (Anything of the form "is there a solution?" when the number of possible solutions is countably infinite)